Specular highlight on a mesh with a normal map becomes squarish at a certain strength
Can someone explain me why the specular highlight becomes more and more square shaped when the strength of the corresponding Normal Map is increased? This is very annoying and I don't understand why it happens and what can I do about it to eliminate this effect.
On the following image the specular reflection of the HDRI on the right is nicely round. It has a strength of 0.02. In the middle with a strength of 0.3 it is already a square.
The mirror image shows the HDRI used. It should create a nice round specular highlight from the sun but instead it looks like it was created by a rectangular area light.
It doesn't matter what form of mesh or what HDRI is used.


I tried other noise textures and it turns out that the shape of the specular highlight is dependent on the texture:
While a Noise texture produces a round higlight

The White Noise texture creates an even sharper rectangular highlight as the Voronoi.

It shouldn't be like this but I can't find a way to solve it.
Maybe a Blender developer would know what is causing this.
